# Jquery Validation messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am new to `Jquery validation plugin`.
I am trying to display the error message return by the validator below the control , currently it is displaying the error message beside the control to validate.

Any help would be appreciated.

My code below

```
  <html>
     <head>
        <title>Index</title>
      <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
      <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('form').validate({  
                rules: {
                    myName: "required",
                    myPassword: "required"
                },
                messages: {
                    myName: "Please specify your name",
                    myPassword: "Please specify your password"
                }
            });
        });
       </script>
     </head>

     <body>

     <form > 



     <label>Username</label> 

     <input type="text" name="myName" id="myName" placeholder="Type your username here..." />  <br/> 



      <label>Password</label> 

         <input type="text" name="myPassword" id="myPassword" placeholder="Type your password     
     here..." /> <br/> 

     <input type="submit" class ="btn btn-primary">

     <button class=""> Clear <br/></button><br/>

    </form> 

    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that error message should appear below from text field then replace your input field with below snippet.

```
<input type="text" name="myName" id="myName" placeholder="Type your username here..."    style="display:block" />
<input type="text" name="myPassword" id="myPassword" placeholder="Type your password     
 here..." style="display:block" />
```

Comment: Is it possible to display the validation message returned by Jquery.Validator inside a span, which is below the control i am validating.

Comment: If i add a span below each input control to validate, Is it possible to show the error message retured by executing the rules in that span.

Comment: Its not possible to put the error messages in custom tags, however if you dont want the error messages in label then just update the below  line from valdator plugin = errorElement: "label" to errorElement: "span",

Comment: Is it possible use jquery validator withour form ?